# Sending postback to ajax loaded user controls

Tags: ajax, postback

I have a set of tabs, which all of them together contain alot of data. I am making the tabs load async. I have one button above the tabs used to save changes. I need this button to send a postback to all the loaded user controls (using [this](http://jamesewelch.com/2008/07/11/how-to-render-a-aspnet-user-control-within-a-web-service-and-return-the-generated-html/)). I need the user control to handle this postback so it can save changes.

What do you think? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried doing it, doesn't work. I am going to have to do some magic with updatepanels and a custom postback.